# index out of range in self summarizer a book

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

```
from transformers import pipeline

summarizer = pipeline('summarization')

summaries = []

if chunks: # Check if chunks is not empty
    for chunk in chunks:
        if chunk.strip(): # Check if chunk is not an empty string
            summary = summarizer(chunk, max_length=100, min_length=30, do_sample=False)[0]['summary_text']
            summaries.append(summary)
```

win I run this code I get this error :

```
Token indices sequence length is longer than the specified maximum sequence length for this model (10020 > 1024). Running this sequence through the model will result in indexing errors
```

I changed the value of max_length and min_length but I get the same error

Answer (score 0):

The error is because your chunk length `10020` is way exceeding the maximum sequence length of `100`.

Here are two suggestions:

1. Increase your sequence length to 512 or whatever the transformer model can hold (you need to check on huggingface documentation).
2. I am posting a snippet which creates `chunk_parts` from a `chunk` each of maximum sequence length `512`.

```
max_chunk_length = 512  # Maximum length of each chunk

if chunks: # Check if chunks is not empty
    for chunk in chunks:
        if chunk.strip(): # Check if chunk is not an empty string
            # Split chunk into smaller chunks
            chunk_parts = [chunk[i:i+max_chunk_length] for i in range(0, len(chunk), max_chunk_length)]
            # Summarize each chunk separately and append to summaries
            for part in chunk_parts:
                summary = summarizer(part, max_length=max_chunk_length, min_length=30, do_sample=False)[0]['summary_text']
                summaries.append(summary)
```